# This toggle script works on all browsers except on internet explorer how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript

Basically I have this script that you can toggle with a button to show or hide an element and if you click any where that is not the button or the targeted element

then it hides that targeted element so I like that as well so it works on all the browsers except on internet explorer. I am currently testing this on internet explorer 11 and it keeps giving me this error

*Object doesn't support property or method 'matches'*

Its referencing to this line of code

if (!event.target.matches('#dropbtn')) {

So how can I get this to work on internet explorer any code examples will be appreciated since I learn best that way and I can't find anything on google that makes sense to me about this problem.

Here is my code

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0].classList.toggle("show");
}

// Prevent event bubble up to window.
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('#dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: lime;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<button id="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown</button>

<div class="dropdown-content" style="background:red; height: 300px;"></div>
```

**Update for future readers**

Look at ***Barmars*** answer and my answer below to understand how you can get this to work successfully.

Comment: Look up the method on MDN. See if it has a polyfill.

Comment: option 1: use jquery, option 2: learn cross browser js

Comment: I looked it up i'm still confused if you know the solution can you provide a code example. If you don't know how then thanks for your response Quentin. I been searching online for a long time to fix this problem on internet explorer.

Comment: Arvind thanks for your response but I can't use jQuery I have to use pure plain JS structure for personal reasons. If I have to change my code enough to have the same effect as this current code I will. I just think it's crazy that nobody from other chat sites I asked this question don't really know how to resolve this in pure JS since every one relies on jQuery and other JS libraries now days. I have nothing against that but nobody really likes to do certain things in pure JS structure any more. Just my opinion.

Comment: And Arvind I been searching and searching do you know how to do this in pure JS? If so can you provide a example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 doesn't have the `matches` method, it calls it `msMatchesSelector`. Use this polyfill from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches#Polyfill) to switch to it automatically.

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The matches function isn't part of the default dom spec. In IE9 and later it's available as msMatchesSelector().

Comment: Patros thanks it works now on internet explorer but it stopped working on the browsers that it use to work on. Any code solutions how I can get this to work on those browsers that use to work on.?

Comment: @DannyLee You should only use `msMatchesSelector` if the browser doesn't have `matches`.

Comment: `var matches = (event.target.matches || event.target.msMatchesSelector); if (!matches('#dropbtn')) { //...`

Comment: dave :( I took your advice but it is not working it gave me this error Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation on chrome neither on edge etc..

Comment: Barmar how can I get it to work on explorer and the other browsers my post code example works on all browsers except on explorer what would be your code example solution here or is it possible to include msMatchesSelector and matches together on the same page with out errors? If I have to change my code to have the same effect with out using ms... and matches...  I will if you guys know how. @Barmar

Comment: @DannyLee I've posted an answer. I just copied the code from the MDN documentation, I don't know why you couldn't do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Barmar** and others who gave me hints wishing they would of just did a full code example of my script instead rather than hints I was able to figure it out thanks to you all.

I just posted ***my answer of the solution***. But I will grant Barmar the vote so future readers look at his answer and ***this code example*** answer to know how to do this successfully.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<style>


.dropbtn{
    background-color: lime;
}



.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}



.show {display:block;}

</style>

<button id="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content" style="background:red; height: 300px;"></div>
  
  <script>

 
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0].classList.toggle("show");
}

// Prevent event bubble up to window.
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content")[0].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
 
/*This section of code makes this compatible with internet explorer 
and non-internet explorer browsers->*/if (!event.target.matches) {
    event.target.matches = event.target.msMatchesSelector;
}
 
  if (!event.target.matches('#dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>
```